# Navigate from stackNavigator to tabNavigator and vice versa

Tags: react-native

I do have `Screen#1` which is part of `stackNavigator`, at some point i want to redirect to `Screen#2` which part of `tabNavigator`

When i try with `({ navigator })` - navigator that is coming as a prop i get this error:

`The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.`

So my question is how to jump from `Screen#1` which is in `stackNavigator` to `Screen#2` which part of `tabNavigator`

and my StackNavigator includes my TabNavigator like this:

TabNavigator:

```
const TabNavigator = () => {
  const currentAccount = useRecoilValue(selectedAccountAtom);
  const { isPinSetUp } = useRecoilValue(authAtom(currentAccount));

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name={Navigators.WALLET} component={WalletNavigator} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Tokens' }} />
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

StackNavigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initRoute} screenOptions={{ headerTitle: '', headerShown: false }}>
  <Stack.Group>
    <Stack.Screen name={Navigators.TAB_NAVIGATOR} component={TabNavigator} />
  </Stack.Group>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: In your case one navigator should be a part of another one. I guess the issue here is - you have a root navigator and two independed ones inside. So, when you are navigating to one of them and try to jump to another - it can't find it in a navigator stack

Comment: Sorry, updated the description, my Tab Navigator is included in my Stack Navigator and when i try to reach from my stack to my Tab Navigator i get not handled error

Comment: But where is a usage of "HomeScreen"? I see it only TAB_NAVIGATOR and WALLET

Comment: WalletNavigator contains `HomeScreen`